# Excel database from WEB in VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba

I would like to make a database of all companies from my city in Excel from this site: [http://panoramafirm.pl/szukaj/małopolskie,olkuski,olkusz/firmy,1](http://panoramafirm.pl/szukaj/ma%C5%82opolskie,olkuski,olkusz/firmy,1)

There are 25 records in every page.

The last number in link is a number of page. Here I've 114 pages and I would like to copy every record from this site to Excel.

After 95 records something goes wrong. The 95th record is overwriting until macro ends up.

```
Sub dwln2()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim xlNowy As Worksheet

    Dim x As Integer

    i = 1

    Z = InputBox("Page from", "Warning", 1)
    x = InputBox("Page to", "Warning", 5)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Olkusz" & x

    For x = Z To x

        Set IE = New InternetExplorer

        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "http://panoramafirm.pl/szukaj/malopolskie,olkuski,olkusz/firmy," & x & ".html"
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        For Each el In IE.document.all
            If el.className = "noLP companyName colorBlue addax addax-cs_hl_hit_company_name_click" Then
                Cells(i, 1) = el.Text
            End If
            If el.className = "noLP addax addax-cs_hl_hit_homepagelink_click icon-link-ext colorBlue" Then
                Cells(i, 2) = el.innerText
            End If
            If el.className = "icon-phone addax addax-cs_hl_hit_phone_number_click noLP highlightOnHover" Then
                Cells(i, 3) = el.innerText
            End If

            If el.className = "contacts" Then
                Cells(i, 4) = el.innerText
            End If

            If el.className = "noLP addax addax-cs_hl_email_submit_click icon-mail titleEmail ajaxGemius colorBlue highlightOnHover" Then
                Cells(i, 5) = el.innerText
            End If
            If el.className = "text hidePhone crl" Then
                Cells(i, 6) = el.innerText
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next

        Set IE = Nothing

        Columns.Select
        Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Second problem is that I don't know how to close InternetExplorer before opening next window. Is there any option to open pages in tabs?

Comment: I updated my answer to reuse the same IE and to store the data in an array before writing it to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 95 doesn't have an element with the classname `text hidePhone crl`

```
Sub dwln2()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim data
    Dim xlNowy As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    Z = InputBox("Page from", "Warning", 1)
    x = InputBox("Page to", "Warning", 5)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Olkusz" & x

    ReDim data(1 To (x - Z + 2) * 25, 1 To 6)

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    For x = Z To x
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "http://panoramafirm.pl/szukaj/malopolskie,olkuski,olkusz/firmy," & x & ".html"
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        For Each el In IE.document.all

            Select Case el.className
            Case "noLP companyName colorBlue addax addax-cs_hl_hit_company_name_click"
                i = i + 1
                data(i, 1) = el.innerText
            Case "noLP addax addax-cs_hl_hit_homepagelink_click icon-link-ext colorBlue"
                data(i, 2) = el.innerText
            Case "icon-phone addax addax-cs_hl_hit_phone_number_click noLP highlightOnHover"
                data(i, 3) = el.innerText
            Case "contacts"
                data(i, 4) = el.innerText
            Case "noLP addax addax-cs_hl_email_submit_click icon-mail titleEmail ajaxGemius colorBlue highlightOnHover"
                data(i, 5) = el.innerText
            Case "text hidePhone crl"
                data(i, 6) = el.innerText
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    Cells.Clear
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data, 1), 6) = data
    Columns.AutoFit
    Rows.AutoFit
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Thomas for help, but in every page are 25 records.

Comment: yours macro copies only the last record in every page. I'd like to get 125 records when I chose range from page 1 to 5. Could you help me?

Comment: unfortunately it makes an error "Run time error (9). Subscript out of range" :/

Comment: Thank you very, very much Thomas! You helped me a lot!